# Different results from different scoring methods with python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, k-fold

I'm working on a NLP project and with different scoring methods, I'm getting different results. for instance

this one gives me 90% +/- 0.6% for accuracy:

```
clf=MLPClassifier()
cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=3, random_state=1)
print (mean(cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=cv,n_jobs=ncore)))
```

this one gives me 80% +/- 0.5% for accuracy:

```
clf=MLPClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
pred_values = clf.predict(X_test)
print( accuracy_score(pred_values, y_test))
```

this one gives me 75% +/- 0.5% for accuracy:

```
clf=MLPClassifier()
print (mean(cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=10,n_jobs=ncore)))
```

I know MLP can produce different results in different runs, but it shouldn't be that much and  it doesn't matter which classifier I'm using even with KNN I have these differences

What's the matter and which one is correct?

Answer (score 0):

First, let us examine each of the methods individually:

1. `RepeatedStratifiedKFold` divides the dataset into n splits, in this case, 10, and makes sure that each fold of the dataset has the same proportion of observations with a given label.
2. `accuracy_score` uses the default split of training and testing data made by the user.
3. Normal `cross_val_score` just divides the dataset into n splits and fits the model n times.

Based on the description, it is pretty obvious that `RepeatedStratifiedKFold` is the best option.